# Python: Import Class: how to disable automatic initialization?

Tags: python, oop

I created the mySimpleFile.py file with class "MySimple"

```
class MySimple (object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        print("from Class",self.name)
 
print ("I do not want this automatically!!!")
```

Now I want to import this class to my another file.

```
import mySimpleFile
 
print("bla bla bla")
```

So I get this:

```
I do not want this automatically!!! 
bla bla bla
```

So how can I disable this initialization?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Put it in an `if __name__` block so that it's only executed if it's the "main" script file, and not if it's imported:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print ("I do not want this automatically!!!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following idiom:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print ("I do not want this automatically!!!")
```

This feature is specifically there to run a portion of code when the file is run directly, *not* when it's imported.

Answer (score 0):

add

```
if __name__ "__main__":
    print("I don't want this")
```

So when you'll import this file, the print won't be execute because it's not the main file